# Should I INSTALL Xubuntu or Lubuntu?

Tags: system

I have a computer from 2013 and it is running windows 10 i have recently started experiencing lag so i want to go for linux mainly lubuntu or xubuntu
these are my specs

[image]

I want basic features like mp3,mp4,fileviewer etc so please help me choose

Comment: whatever you feel like using ;-) a system that runs w10 even when a bit laggy will run ANY Ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: Lag in W10 could have many causes. It might be easier to simply fix whatever you W10 problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Both OS works fine in your System.

**Recommended Minimum System Requirements for Xubuntu**

The **minimum system requirements** for this release of Xubuntu are 512 MB of system memory (RAM).

5 GB of disk space and a graphics card and monitor capable of at least 800×600 pixels resolution.

where as **Lubuntu**,

The **minimum system requirements for Lubuntu** are a Pentium II or Celeron CPU with PAE support.

128 MB of RAM.

at least 2 GB of hard-drive space. This release also still supports PowerPC architecture, requiring a G4 867 MHz processor and 640 MB of RAM minimum.

compared to Xubuntu, Lubuntu is actually **lightweight**.

The difference is Xubuntu comes with some inbuilt features where in Lubuntu You need to install it manually.
According to your Pc configuration Xubuntu is **best** because it comes with pre-installed tools that make it much easier to use.

Further details: https://xubuntu.org/about/

Lubuntu features: https://lubuntu.net/lubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-released